# setWindowFields for rank aggregations makes filtering extremely slow

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I’m currently building an aggregation pipeline to get a rank of a user based on a certain property.
The pipeline looks as follows:

```
[
  {
    $setWindowFields:
      /**
       * query: The query in MQL.
       */
      {
        sortBy: {
          kills: -1,
        },
        output: {
          denseRankQuantityForState: {
            $denseRank: {},
          },
        },
      },
  },
  {
    $project:
      {
        _id: "$_id",
        type: "$type",
        xuid: "$xuid",
        kills: "$kills",
        rank: "$denseRankQuantityForState",
      },
  },
  {
    $match:
      {
        xuid: "my_xuid",
        type: 0,
      },
  },
]
```

There are indexes for type, xuid and type + xuid as a compound index.

It seems though that MongoDB is not able to leverage any of these indexes in the final matching step. Since that collection has over 4 million document entries, the query is way too slow (it exceeds the normal execution time limit.

Is there anything I can do to tell MongoDB to use one of my indexes?

Comment: An index on `kills` may be useful.

Comment: In what manner would you like MongoDB to use one of the two indexes that you mention?

Comment: The `$setWindowFields` stage requires that it has to read **every** document, thus an index on type + xuid does not help.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  I do not want to improve the speed of the setWindowFields function, that is already pretty fast. I want MongoDB to use the indexes in the last step, the filtering for the right document.

Comment: @user20042973 I would like Mongo to use the indexes on type and xuid to find the documents in the result from the setWindowFunction & project. Since the relation of Document => xuid / type is still intact, I was hoping there was some way to tell MongoDB to use the indexes for that.

Comment: Try to put the `$match` stage before the `$project`. A `$project` stage "destroys" an index use. See [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It seems that setWindowFields also destroys index uses. Even after I switched out the match and project stages, the match statement itself still takes incredibly long